# Linear independence of position states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states

I was reading some notes from a second-semester quantum mechanics course and had trouble understanding why position states of a particle moving along the real line $\mathbb{R}$ are linearly independent. Here is an excerpt from the notes:

> Roughly, $\lvert x \rangle$
>   represents the state of the system where the particle is at the position $x$. The full state
>   space requires position states $\lvert x \rangle$  $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Physically, we consider all of these
>   states to be linearly independent: the state of a particle at some point $x_0$ can’t be build by
>   superposition of states where the particle is elsewhere.

Can we prove that any two position states $\lvert x \rangle$ and $\lvert x' \rangle$ with $x\neq x'$ are linearly independent or is there an intuitive way to see why this is true?

Comment: The key word is "Roughly". To understand this properly requires advanced functional analysis and operator theory. We get many Questions about how to understand position states or energy continuum states rigorously but I don't think the Answers are helpful without the math.

Comment: As always for a request for rigor in physics, the real question is, what do you want to start from? In the standard setup, this holds by the definition of $\hat{x}$, which is made to reflect how position behaves in reality.

Comment: In other words, this is a difficult question because I don't know of any reasonable way to define $\hat{x}$ that doesn't boil down to _assuming_ the thing you want to prove.

Comment: @knzhou one of the answers given below worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) DEFINE an operator $x$ such that the states $|x'\rangle$ are its eigenstates; $x|x'\rangle=x'|x'\rangle$. Note that such an $x$ is $\textbf{self-adjoint}$-$x^\dagger=x$.

2) We know from finite dimensional linear algebra that self adjoint, or $\textbf{hermitian}$ operators have eigenstates that form a basis for the given vector space they are defined over(this is a standard theorem so I skip the proof). If they form a basis, then BY DEFINITION the eigenstates are linearly independent.

3) Things are a little subtle in infinite dimensional vector spaces(the ones we usually deal with in QM), and to get around that, we make the following 'postulate'-These self adjoint operators, called 'observables;, have a $\textbf{complete set of eigenstates}$, and our hilbert space is such that it is spanned by these. In other words, we CHOOSE/DEFINE our hilbert space to be spanned by the eigenstates of an observable. Here, $x$ is such an observable, and so $|x'\rangle$ provides such a spanning set.

4) The transition from the basis vectors being linearly independent to being orthogonal is again familiar-Gram Schmidt orthogonalization allows you to replace the linearly independent basis vectors with orthogonal vectors. For hermitian operators, this happens automatically-eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal(the proof is trivial). Things get a little complicated in case there is degeneracy i.e. distinct eigenvectors have the same eigenvalue.

5) The usual orthogonality condition in finite dimensional spaces is $\langle u_m|u_n\rangle=\delta_{mn}$.  When the index $n$ becomes CONTINUOUS, we have to generalise this appropriately. In this example, we have the states $|x'\rangle$, parametrized by the continuous parameter $x'$, and so the kronecker delta(for discrete indices)  generalises to the dirac delta(counterpart for continuous arguments)-$\langle x'|x"\rangle=\delta(x'-x")$.

6) In summary, the key point is that the eigenstates $|x\rangle$ are eigenstates of an observable, thus they form(by definition) a basis of our hilbert space, and are thus orthogonal and thus linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac notation that you are employing, with bras and kets, is an abstract notation. Great for manipulation, derivations, and tidying. Not apt for actual calculations.

For that, you need to choose a *particular representation*. I.e. a function to represent $|x\rangle$ so that you can do maths with it.

Usually, the position representation is used, which maps the bras/kets to functions in real space ($x$):

- $|x_1\rangle \rightarrow \delta(x-x_1)$
- $|x_2\rangle \rightarrow \delta(x-x_2)$
- $\langle x_2 |x_1 \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x \, \delta(x-x_1)\delta(x-x_2) = \delta(x_1-x_2)$

where $\delta(x_1-x_2)$ is $0$ if $x_1\neq x_2$, and infinity for $x_1=x_2$. To be normalised, this should be $1$. Delta functions are known to have this issue, and they are not properly functions but distributions, so they cannot be normalised. This begs the question on whether or not it makes sense to use a delta function at all, and in fact finite-sized wavepackets are often used instead.

The above would be a proof. 
 The intuitive way is to think about the interpretation of these states. If a particle is at location $x_1$, it cannot be at location $x_2$.

Comment: The inner product evaluates to a continuous delta functions, $\delta(x_1 - x_2)$. The states are orthogonal but not normalised.

Comment: @lux Touche'. I corrected it/

Comment: @SuperCiocia why can the infinity be "normalized" to 1?

Comment: @EduardoMunguia because I was trying to be sloppy and quick about it. I changed the answer now.